# SQL One to Many Condition Issue

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have two tables

```
Table1 (Users)
ID,   NAME,        COUNTRY
1,    Joe Bloggs,  1
2,    Joe Jnr,     1
3,    Joe Snr,     2

Table2 (Orders)
UsersID,  Product
1,        Apple TV
1,        iPad Pro
1,        MacBook Pro
2,        iPad Mini
2,        iPad Pro
3,        iPad Air
3,        iPad Pro
```

If i wanted a list of products bought if user lives in Country = 1

```
Select Orders.Product from users left join Users.ID = ORDERS.ID WHERE COUNTRY = 1
```

works fine

What if though I wanted a list of products bought if user lives in country = 1 and brought macbook Pro (but not show the macbook pro in the list)

So just show

```
AppleTV 
iPAD pRO
```

Comment: what do you mean (but not show the macbook pro in the list)? Could you provide a sample output for your query for better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing in classic SQL you have a layered sub-select.
Code that should work:

```
    Select Product from Orders
Where Product <> 'MacBook Pro'  -- you don't want MacBook Pro in results
and UsersID in
(Select ID from Users
 where country = '1'   --get all Country 1 users that Purchased MacBooks
 and ID in
 (Select B.UsersID
  from Orders B  --- aliased for clarity
  where  Product = 'MacBook Pro'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer for that is simple. First, select the users who bought a MacBook Pro and who are living in that country:

```
SELECT T_USERS.id
FROM Users T_USERS INNER JOIN Orders T_ORDERS
ON (T_USERS.id = T_ORDERS.UsersID)
WHERE T_USERS.Country = 1
    AND T_ORDERS.product = 'MacBook Pro'
```

And, then, use it in a subquery to get the users and avoid the rows containing the MacBook Product:

```
SELECT Product 
FROM   Orders 
WHERE  product <> 'MacBook Pro' 
       AND UsersID IN (SELECT T_USERS.id 
                       FROM   Users T_USERS  INNER JOIN Orders T_ORDERS 
                       ON ( T_USERS.id = T_ORDERS.UsersID ) 
                       WHERE  T_USERS.country = 1 
                              AND T_ORDERS.product = 'MacBook Pro')
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Select distinct o1.Product 
        from Orders o1
        inner join Orders o2
        on o1.UserId = o2.UserId
        and o2.Product = 'MacBook Pro'
        inner join Users u
        on o1.UserId = u.Id
        where o1.Product <> 'MacBook Pro'
        and u.country = 1
        order by o1.Product
```